# How to instantiate object of a collection in App.xaml.cs dynamically from code in Windows Phone App?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want to instantiate object of a collection in App.xaml.cs dynamically from MainPage.xaml.cs when required so that I can used the object throughout the app pages. I can manually instantiate and keep for current requirement but after my app is published and requirement increases than I don't know how to get it.
Can somebody give me any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your App.xaml.cs, declare your Collection

```
public ObservableCollection<Person> personsList = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
```

Then in your MainPage.xaml.cs, assign the collection values to the collection object

```
(Application.Current as App).personsList = mypersonsList;
```

After this, you can access the values from anypage in the app

```
 ObservableCollection<Person> mypersonsList = (Application.Current as App).personsList;
```