# MVC in WPF: Where to initialize the Model?

Tags: .net, wpf, design-patterns, model-view-controller

I'm just learning WPF and design patterns at the same time.
Now i'm creating some simple application using MVC pattern, which simulating some kind of schedule (with ability of editing it by user). And I'm guided by this great [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23241/Using-MVC-to-Unit-Test-WPF-Applications). There are several Views (with its' own Controllers, naturally) in my app, which have a DataGrid for displaying schedule information from one Model. All these Views are of course should be independent from each other. The Model is a class that inherited from `ObservableCollection<>`.
The question is: where it's better to initialize this Model to provide an ability for using it by these several Views at the same time? As a field of `Application` class? Or maybe in `Application.Resources`?

> I know, that my question may be obvious for you, but it's not for me. So help please, if it's not a problem for you. :)

Comment: Use MVVM  for WPF,  not MVC.

Comment: @HighCore, I know, that for WPF MVVM is the best. But in this case I use MVC just for educational purposes. However, MVC isn't impossible for WPF. :)

Comment: If you are learning WPF I would recommend choosing MVVM over MVC. It is a better fit for WPF and you will find it easier to learn as there is a LOT more online resources for WPF & MVVM than WPF & MVC. That article is 7 years old now and I expect Josh Smith himself would probably prefer MVVM now.

Comment: @GlenThomas, yeah, I realized it, because there are quite not many articles about MVC in WPF. But now I'm trying to implement MVC just to get acquainted with this design pattern. Moreover, as I understood, MVVM is an evolution of MVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using it for educational purposes like you said I think you'll have a better experience if initialize it on App.xaml.cs

Comment: Ok, thanks. If i'll make it a field in this 'Application' class, would it notify the Views about changes in collection?

Comment: Look this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14228496/how-to-instantiate-object-of-a-collection-in-app-xaml-cs-dynamically-from-code-i)

Comment: Oh, thanks again. As I understood, the answer is "yes". :)